# Are P-names the codes used to define all possible membership relations that could be Forced from a Countable Model of Set Theory?

Tags: forcing

Is the following anywhere close to a possible meaning of P-Names in Forcing, based upon a countable model M of Set Theory and the addition of a new set G and its associated model M[G] ?:

1) If the membership relation for each set in a model of set theory has been fully determined then the model is fully determined.

2) The Forcing Relation can be used to determine the complete membership relation for all sets in M[G] by specifying each element a in each set b in the model, where p is a forcing condition (i.e. an element p in a p.o. P $\supset$ G, with a,b,p,P $\in$ M) via a complete set of forcing conditions of the form:

p $\Vdash$ a $\in_G$ b ..................(i)

3) This Forced membership relation (i) can be coded in M as a triple in a,b,p:

< a,p > $\in$  b (i.e. b = { < a,p > , ...}) .................(ii)

within M. All possible sets of triples "< a,p > $\in$  b" that can be known to M are present within M, but as G isn't known to M, M will not know which of these triples will be part of the actual selected Forcing relation $\Vdash$. These sets of triples are equivalent to P-Names and represent all possible 'part' membership relations of any full $\in_G$ that could be forced and could be known to M.

4) The P-Names can be translated between M[G] and M by using the Shoenfield's Unramified Forcing paper definition, which 'looks' to be equivalent to relating (i) and (ii) above:

a $\in_G$ b $\leftrightarrow$ p $\in$ G AND < a,p > $\in$  b .........(iii)

where a,b,p are sets in M, the difference being in M[G] under $\in_G$ the elements of the sets can be different from $\in$ in M (which I thought was a particularly neat part of Shoenfield's Unramified Forcing paper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it all looks good. I assume you're reading Shoenfield's paper, still IMO one of the best treatments of forcing in set theory (for the classical results). Let me add a few remarks.

For your point (1), "determined" here specifically means: the [Mostowski collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostowski_collapse_lemma) of the structure $(M,\in_G)$ is the model $M[G]$. (Shoenfield points this out.) The collapse function is called $K_G$ by Shoenfield (also $a\mapsto\bar{a}$).

Usually people don't apply the collapse to all of $M$, but to an inductively defined subset $V^P$:
$$\begin{align*}
 V_0^P &= \varnothing\\
 V_{\alpha+1}^P &= \mathcal{P}(V_\alpha^P\times P)\\
 V_\lambda^P &= \bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}V_\alpha^P\\
 V^P &= \bigcup_{\alpha\in\Omega^M}V_\alpha^P
\end{align*}$$
However $K_G(b)$ will ignore any elements not of the form $\langle a,p\rangle$; they are "chaff", "non-coding DNA".

If you're familiar with boolean-valued models, there one inductively defines a set of functions with values in the boolean algebra $B$: $F_0=\varnothing$, $F_{\alpha+1}$ is all functions (in $M$) with domain $F_\alpha$ and range in $B$, etc. Observe how close this is to the $V^P_\alpha$'s, thus: Take an element $f$ of $V^P_{\alpha+1}$; for any $a\in V^P_\alpha$, collect all the pairs $\langle a,p\rangle$ occuring in $f$; gather all these $p$'s to form a set of conditions. So $f$ is "essentially" a function with domain $V^P_\alpha$ taking values in the boolean algebra of sets of conditions.

Your point (3) gets at the heart of technique: each element of $V^P$ is a "name" of an element of $M[G]$. Inhabitants of $M$ can discuss elements of $M[G]$ using these names---they can say things like "$a$ is a potential element of $b$", "if condition $p$ is true, according to $G$, then $a$ really is an element of $b$". But since they don't know what's in $G$, they won't know the actual values of these names (i.e., they can't compute $K_G$).

Shoenfield's *forcing language* is just the standard language of ZF, augmented with all these names, and interpreting $\in$ as $\in_G$.

I wrote up a set of [notes](https://michaelcweiss.files.wordpress.com/2019/03/smullyan.pdf) as a kind of gloss on Shoenfield's paper (and other things; $\S21$ is about forcing). It's at [diagonalargument.com](https://diagonalargument.com/mathnotes/set-theory-meetup/).

Comment: OK thanks. Your notes have many 'understanding insights' that can't be seen with foresight & only hindsight, so I will carefully read your notes & numerous articles in diagonalargument. Thanks also for confirming "non-coding DNA" - I had thought I had missed something when noticing that the membership definition 'seemed to ignore' non P-names, but you have confirmed its actually true (I think the definition is actually quite neat - by doing that in a simple no-fuss sort of way).

Comment: any chance of a link to the accompanying "Basics
of First-order Logic" in notes (e.g. to see §10 in L/F) ?

Comment: The diagonalargument.com link I gave takes you to the page for the set-theory meetup, which has a link to the Basic Logic notes

Comment: Shoenfield’s paper is “no muss, no fuss”, one of the things I like about it. But I think leaving out the $V^P$ hierarchy makes it less clear what’s going on. Also, the chaff would be a problem for symmetric models. (Shoenfield uses the HOD approach instead.)

Comment: Ah, indeed it is in diagonalargument.com - I was saving that as a treat for after reading your notes - should have gone for a breadth first search ! Before I started reading Shoelfield's paper I was totally mystified about what a P-Name was (being a novice...).